# How to Dynamically Create Spark ML Pipeline

Tags: json, web-services, apache-spark-ml

I am building a simple web service where an user can easily construct a Spark ML pipeline in the UI and persist it so that the user can retrieve the saved pipeline and start to train it.

Here is the idea:

1. User can select a model and evaluator and fill in the parameters to form a pipeline in the UI
2. User can specify the output directory to save this pipeline
3. User hits save and the pipeline will be created under the specified directory

After brainstorming, I got follwoing implementation idea:

1. Spin up two server: Web server and Spark cluster
2. When user hits the save button, export the user defined pipeline metadata in `JSON` format and send it to the Spark cluster
3. The Spark cluster takes the `JSON` and instantiates the pipeline in `SparkContext`
4. Save the instantiated pipeline in the specified directory by using `Spark ML Persistence`

The challenge I am facing now is how to convert and export the pipeline metadata into `JSON`, and consequently how to parse and instantiate a pipeline from `JSON` in Spark (in the step 2 and 3).

I believe I can write a simple `converter` and `parser` by myself, but I am just wondering if there is any libraries or frameworks I can use to get me started.

---

**Update**

Because there is no code involved in front-end, I cannot use the Spark's ML persistence or MLeap.

Answer (score 0):

If you use spark ml's format to save the json from the web server, you can just load it and that will create a pipeline. Looking at the serialized json and the code to generate it, it seems straightforward to do so.

Comment: What do you mean by Spark ML's format? Does Spark deserialize a ml pipeline into `JSON` format?

Comment: Yes. a "Pipeline" object is saved as a directory tree and individual stages as json. Try saving it and opening the saved files.

Comment: The serialization looks straightforward, yet it can be challenging to manually generate one. Because an user provides only a model name and associated parameters and **no code** from the UI, it's inevitable to translate the specification and serialize into this format manually... Is there any walk around for this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [MLeap](https://github.com/combust/mleap), it support most Spark ML pipelines feature transformers and estimators. You have an option to serialize to json or to protobuf for really large models (i.e. Random Forest)